# How to insert only the exact matches into the column using SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have just started working on a population dataset for SQLite practice. I have two tables(A & B) having the city as one of their columns. However, the number of rows differs in both tables. Also, neither of them has any primary key.

| City_fromTblA |
| --- |
| Delhi |
| Mumbai |
| Kolkatta |
| Agra |
| Noida |
| Mathura |

| City_fromTblB |
| --- |
| Mumbai |
| Agra |
| Kolkatta |
| Noida |

I want to create a new table that will have 2 columns- City_fromTblA, City_fromtblB.

City_fromTblA will have all rows

City_fromTblB will have city_name in only those rows which have exact matches, others should be NULL.

How can this be achieved?
Something like this,

| City_fromTblA | City_fromTblB |
| --- | --- |
| Delhi | NULL |
| Mumbai | Mumbai |
| Kolkatta | Kolkatta |
| Agra | Agra |
| Noida | Noida |
| Mathura | NULL |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a left join:

```
insert into new_table
select City_fromTblA, City_fromTblB
from tableA
left join tableB on City_fromTblA = City_fromTblB
```